# Connect Python with bitbucket

Tags: python, authorization, bitbucket

Hey im trying to connect python with bitbucket but it keep saying that i need to create an app password although im using my app password, what am i doing wrong?

```
 url = 'https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/user/'

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', "Authorization":"Bearer token"}

    r = requests.get(url, auth=('email', 'password'), headers=headers)

    print(r.status_code)

    print(r.text)
```

Comment: the answere is in here: https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/connect-python-with-bitbucket/55945/8

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to create an app password, which is different from your regular username/password. You can [find this in your settings](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/).

Comment: I created one and put it in the "token"  in "Authorization":"Bearer token"

Comment: From what [I can see in the docs](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/), you should use it as a user password, but only for a single application/purpose.

Comment: do you mean put it in   r = requests.get(url, auth=('email', 'password'), headers=headers) insted of the 'password'? if i do it i get an 401 message

Comment: You need to consult the documentation for how to use it. Some online resources mention having to base64 encode the basic auth information. I don't use bitbucket so can't answer for sure, these security topics also change over time.